# How to Parse result of Parse Cloud Function to Struct?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server

HI i have a parse cloud function that return a Dictionary  like

```
return {
          success: false,
          message: "User has no Company",
          total: 0,
          materials: [],
        };
```

where materials is an array of PFObject

Materials are PFObjects subclassed in IOS ( Parse ios SDK )

i call the function in this way:

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "getMaterials", withParameters: ["skip":0, "take": 20]) {
            (response, error) in
            // HOW HERE?
        }
```

how i can convert directly the response into a struct

defined like

```
struct MaterialeResults {
    var materials : [Materiale]
    var message: String?
    var success: Bool?
    var total: Int?
}
```

thank you

Comment: Create a class and register it as a custom class with the parse sdk.

Comment: Tried but the problem is casting to the Class. 

``` 
import Foundation
import Parse

class MaterialeResults : PFObject {
    var materials : [Materiale]?
    var message: String?
    var success: Bool?
    var total: Int?
}

extension MaterialeResults: PFSubclassing {
    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "MaterialeResults"
    }
}
``` is not parsed